# Rating based off of number of comments or views

Tags: comments, rating

Is it possible to  have some sort of rating feature based off of x amount of comments or views?

#### Example:

Instead of saying 200 views, have it say:

> "Hot"

400 views, have it say:

> "Very Hot"

#### something similar to a if else statement

> value=200
> Echo "hot"
> if else
> echo "cold"

Comment: How do you track/count your views?

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? It is a legitimate question. There are many WordPress plugins to count post views. Do you have any solution for this already working?

Comment: @pogoking The downvotes are probably for _does not show any research effort_. Please tell us next time what you have tried already. Add some code, and you _will_ get upvotes. Anyway, welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! :)

Comment: Thanks pogoking 7 i've asked a couple questions in the past and seems to always be downgraded. I become very hestitant to ever ask anything. I have researched this and seem to always stumble  on just comment counters, nothing that ouputs and adds up.

Comment: As @toscho pointed out, you will have to show use some _research effort_. And this doesn't mean "this plugin doesn't do what I want". It's more like "this is what I've read up, here's my concept". And please keep in mind, that this site is _not_ about plugin recommendations. See the [faq].

Comment: Additional note: Downvotes can (and will - at least by me) removed if the question gets reworked/-written and a comment is left that notifies me.

Answer (score 3):

I would not take visits into account: To get these numbers you have to connect to an external table, or *worse* write into the WordPress tables on each request.

Use comments, that is built-in. Here is a sample code that adjusts itself to your comment development:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_78513_hotness' );

function wpse_78513_hotness( $content )
{
    static $average = FALSE;

    static $global_stats = NULL;

    if ( FALSE === $average )
        $average = round( wp_count_posts()->publish / wp_count_comments()->approved );

    $current_comments = wp_count_comments( get_the_ID() )->approved;

    $hotness = 'lukewarm';

    if ( $current_comments >= ( $average * 1.5 ) )
        $hotness = 'hot';

    if ( $current_comments <= ( $average / 2 ) )
        $hotness = 'cold';

    $stats = "<p class='hotness'>Hotness: $hotness</p>";

    return $stats . $content;
}
```

It counts posts and comment on the first call and stores these data in an internal static variable to save time on further calls. Then it takes the comment count for the current post and calculates how much it differs from the average.

You can and should extend it. It is a guide, not a complete solution.

Comment: How would i than output it to show those filters or does that do it for both?

Comment: It seems that code takes an input of some sortof rating then ouputs as "lukewarm" etc is this true?

Comment: @Splinner No, it doesn’t take any extra input, just the data offered by your installation by default.